# Does magento2.4 sanitizes form input in order to avoid XSS or I have to implement my own methods?

Tags: magento2.4, security, adminform

I made my first form:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_form.customer_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blogpost Actions</item>
        <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>content</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
        <deps>
            <dep>add_blogpost.blogpost_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="blogpost">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Blog Post</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="blog_post_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="title" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label>Title</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="content" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Contents</label>
                <dataScope>content</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg>
                    <settings>
                        <rows>5</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>

    </fieldset>

    <dataSource name="blogpost_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="*/*/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider
            class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost\DataProvider"
            name="blogpost_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>blog_post_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
</form>
```

And I handle the submission like this:

```
<?php

namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Controller\Adminhtml\BlogpostForm;

use Laminas\Stdlib\ParametersInterface;
use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected BlogPost $blogPostModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        BlogPost $blogPostModel
    ) {
        $this->blogPostModel = $blogPostModel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /**
         * @var  ParametersInterface
         */
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        // I assume that there's no id for now
        // @todo check what happens upon id providing

        $this->blogPostModel->setTitle($data['blogpost']['title']);
        $this->blogPostModel->setContent($data['blogpost']['content']);


    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Does Magento 2.4 sanitizes data for XSS or I upon model saving I must sanitize the data on my own (either via php's `strip_tags` or via `HtmlPurifier`)?

Answer (score 0):

since you are implementing a new form you should sanitize your inputs for xss but most importantly the output to the user.

Sanitizing the input will guarantee that a compromised content or title will not be saved but in the case of someone acutely managing to get the compromised values in your database it's equally important to santise the output for example

`$block->escapeJs($content);`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html